# Regex Not Matching Unicode

Tags: c#, regex, unicode, character-properties

How would I go about using Regex to match Unicode strings? I'm loading in a couple keywords from a text file and using them with Regex on another file. The keywords both contain unicode (such as `á`, etc).  I'm not sure where the problem is. Is there some option I have to set?

---

Code:

```
foreach (string currWord in _keywordList)
{
    MatchCollection mCount = Regex.Matches(
        nSearch.InnerHtml, "\\b" + @currWord + "\\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (mCount.Count > 0)
    {
        wordFound.Add(currWord);
        MessageBox.Show(@currWord, mCount.ToString());
    }
}
```

And reading the keywords to a list:

```
var rdComp = new StreamReader(opnDiag.FileName);
string compSplit = rdComp.ReadToEnd()
                         .Replace("\r\n", "\n")
                         .Replace("\n\r", "\n");
rdComp.Dispose();
string[] compList = compSplit.Split(new[] {'\n'});
```

Then I change the array to a list.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your code that's using the regex? It could be a charset problem (e.g., nothing to do with regex), or a regex problem, or...

Comment: What regex are you using and how? Show some code, please.

Comment: Do the keywords always start and end with word characters (i.e., letters, digits or underscores)?

Comment: It looks like this should work.  Can you reduce it to a single regex scenario that fails to match?

Answer (score 1):

When matching on a specific character, I believe regular expressions only support literals for the ASCII character set.  Beyond that, you can use \uxxxx to match on the Unicode code point.

See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Comment: I'm not sure that's the problem. She/he isn't using character classes but verbatim strings, surrounded by word boundaries.

Comment: @Pietzcker - That's the problem.  S/he needs to parse the string and add each character as a unicode code point.

Comment: Well, I've just tried using Unicode literals in a regex in C#, and it worked perfectly. `Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("It BӦЯӁڀ!", @"\bBӦЯӁڀ\b", "works"));` returns `It works!`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [\u0000-\uffff]+ to match at least the BMP