# match exact arabic word using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, unicode, arabic

I am new to regular expressions and I need a regular expression to match exact `Arabic` word using regular expression in a string. I have created [this](http://regexr.com/3aq7i) regexr, but it returning 423 matches when there are less than 10 actual word matches in the given string. What should I modify in the regular expression to match the exact arabic word?

**EDIT:**

I am trying with the following regular expression:

```
[الإمارات]+
```

I have tried with `word boundary(\b)` which is working for English words but it is not working for Arabic words.

Comment: Do not put code in a link. Show us the code. Also, tell us the dialect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary: Based on your comments about wanting to match repetitions of such words, it seems like `\b(?:[ لإمارات]+\b\s*)+` should work for you.

---

These are your matches:

1. ‎ت
2. ‎ر
3. ‎الإمارات
4. ‎ال
5. ‎ر
6. ‎المت
7. ‎ال
8. ‎ل
9. ‎ال
10. ‎ت
11. ‎الت
12. ‎لم
13. ‎م
14. ‎ر
15. ‎ل
16. ‎ت
17. ‎ا
18. ‎ال
19. ‎ر
20. ‎ال
21. ‎ت
22. ‎ال
23. ‎ال
24. ‎ات
25. ‎ال
26. ‎ا
27. ‎إ
28. ‎ا
29. ‎ات
30. ‎ا
31. ‎ال
32. ‎ا
33. ‎ل
34. ‎ل
35. ‎ال
36. ‎م
37. ‎ما
38. ‎ات
39. ‎ل
40. ‎لا
41. ‎ا
42. ‎ا
43. ‎ا
44. ‎ال
45. ‎ا
46. ‎ا
47. ‎ا
48. ‎م
49. ‎ال
50. ‎لما
51. ‎ا
52. ‎ال
53. ‎الم
54. ‎م
55. ‎م
56. ‎ر
57. ‎ا
58. ‎ت
59. ‎ل
60. ‎ا
61. ‎ر
62. ‎م
63. ‎م
64. ‎ر
65. ‎الا
66. ‎ا
67. ‎ت
68. ‎ر
69. ‎ا
70. ‎م
71. ‎ر
72. ‎ال
73. ‎ام
74. ‎ات
75. ‎ال
76. ‎ار
77. ‎م
78. ‎ت
79. ‎ل
80. ‎الإ
81. ‎ا
82. ‎ر
83. ‎الم
84. ‎ا
85. ‎ر
86. ‎الر
87. ‎ا
88. ‎ال
89. ‎م
90. ‎ال
91. ‎ا
92. ‎ما
93. ‎م
94. ‎ارات
95. ‎م
96. ‎المت
97. ‎را
98. ‎ت
99. ‎م
100. ‎ا
101. ‎ت
102. ‎ام
103. ‎الت
104. ‎ل
105. ‎ا
106. ‎ا
107. ‎لا
108. ‎م
109. ‎ل
110. ‎ال
111. ‎ال
112. ‎الم
113. ‎ال
114. ‎م
115. ‎م
116. ‎ل
117. ‎م
118. ‎ر
119. ‎ل
120. ‎ال
121. ‎ال
122. ‎ر
123. ‎الم
124. ‎م
125. ‎للم
126. ‎ا
127. ‎م
128. ‎م
129. ‎ل
130. ‎الما
131. ‎ل
132. ‎ت
133. ‎ا
134. ‎تماما
135. ‎ا
136. ‎ا
137. ‎لل
138. ‎ا
139. ‎الت
140. ‎ت
141. ‎مل
142. ‎الت
143. ‎إل
144. ‎ت
145. ‎ا
146. ‎ر
147. ‎إ
148. ‎ا
149. ‎ال
150. ‎ل
151. ‎للإمارات
152. ‎الم
153. ‎ل
154. ‎الرا
155. ‎الت
156. ‎ل
157. ‎م
158. ‎ل
159. ‎ل
160. ‎ر
161. ‎ال
162. ‎ر
163. ‎الا
164. ‎ت
165. ‎ا
166. ‎ل
167. ‎ر
168. ‎ات
169. ‎ا
170. ‎مت
171. ‎ت
172. ‎ر
173. ‎الإمارات
174. ‎لا
175. ‎ما
176. ‎ا
177. ‎ات
178. ‎ال
179. ‎ا
180. ‎ال
181. ‎ارات
182. ‎الإ
183. ‎ا
184. ‎ات
185. ‎ال
186. ‎ارات
187. ‎الت
188. ‎ل
189. ‎م
190. ‎ت
191. ‎ر
192. ‎ت
193. ‎ر
194. ‎م
195. ‎ال
196. ‎ل
197. ‎ال
198. ‎ت
199. ‎الم
200. ‎ات
201. ‎تل
202. ‎ال
203. ‎ام
204. ‎ما
205. ‎ا
206. ‎ت
207. ‎م
208. ‎ا
209. ‎الرا
210. ‎م
211. ‎ر
212. ‎ر
213. ‎ال
214. ‎ا
215. ‎ر
216. ‎ا
217. ‎م
218. ‎ا
219. ‎ل
220. ‎ال
221. ‎ر
222. ‎ر
223. ‎ما
224. ‎ت
225. ‎ال
226. ‎مر
227. ‎ال
228. ‎ل
229. ‎ما
230. ‎لت
231. ‎ر
232. ‎ا
233. ‎ا
234. ‎ال
235. ‎مر
236. ‎لل
237. ‎ر
238. ‎ل
239. ‎م
240. ‎ا
241. ‎ا
242. ‎ام
243. ‎ا
244. ‎ال
245. ‎ا
246. ‎ت
247. ‎ر
248. ‎ل
249. ‎ال
250. ‎م
251. ‎ال
252. ‎ل
253. ‎ل
254. ‎ال
255. ‎ا
256. ‎ا
257. ‎ممت
258. ‎ل
259. ‎ال
260. ‎لم
261. ‎لت
262. ‎ا
263. ‎ال
264. ‎ا
265. ‎ل
266. ‎ا
267. ‎ل
268. ‎ا
269. ‎ال
270. ‎را
271. ‎ل
272. ‎م
273. ‎ت
274. ‎م
275. ‎ر
276. ‎م
277. ‎الل
278. ‎ل
279. ‎ما
280. ‎الل
281. ‎ا
282. ‎ت
283. ‎ا
284. ‎ت
285. ‎ما
286. ‎ر
287. ‎ت
288. ‎ما
289. ‎الا
290. ‎ت
291. ‎ا
292. ‎ال
293. ‎ا
294. ‎ت
295. ‎ت
296. ‎م
297. ‎م
298. ‎ما
299. ‎ل
300. ‎ال
301. ‎ا
302. ‎ال
303. ‎ال
304. ‎ا
305. ‎را
306. ‎الت
307. ‎ل
308. ‎ال
309. ‎ت
310. ‎الإمارات
311. ‎ل
312. ‎ا
313. ‎م
314. ‎ا
315. ‎للت
316. ‎الامت
317. ‎ا
318. ‎لت
319. ‎م
320. ‎ا
321. ‎ل
322. ‎ا
323. ‎ما
324. ‎ل
325. ‎ما
326. ‎ت
327. ‎ا
328. ‎ر
329. ‎ل
330. ‎ل
331. ‎ل
332. ‎ل
333. ‎الإمارات
334. ‎م
335. ‎ال
336. ‎ل
337. ‎ا
338. ‎ال
339. ‎ل
340. ‎ل
341. ‎ا
342. ‎ال
343. ‎الم
344. ‎الت
345. ‎ت
346. ‎م
347. ‎ا
348. ‎ا
349. ‎ت
350. ‎ا
351. ‎ا
352. ‎إ
353. ‎ار
354. ‎الإ
355. ‎ت
356. ‎ا
357. ‎ال
358. ‎الم
359. ‎ال
360. ‎ال
361. ‎ام
362. ‎ال
363. ‎لا
364. ‎ال
365. ‎ر
366. ‎لال
367. ‎ل
368. ‎ال
369. ‎لا
370. ‎ات
371. ‎المت
372. ‎ر
373. ‎ا
374. ‎ما
375. ‎ر
376. ‎ل
377. ‎ات
378. ‎ت
379. ‎م
380. ‎ل
381. ‎ر
382. ‎ل
383. ‎م
384. ‎ت
385. ‎ت
386. ‎تل
387. ‎الرمال
388. ‎ر
389. ‎ما
390. ‎ا
391. ‎ل
392. ‎م
393. ‎ا
394. ‎لل
395. ‎ال
396. ‎ر
397. ‎ال
398. ‎إل
399. ‎م
400. ‎ل
401. ‎ت
402. ‎ال
403. ‎ر
404. ‎م
405. ‎ا
406. ‎م
407. ‎لا
408. ‎ل
409. ‎م
410. ‎الإ
411. ‎رار
412. ‎ا
413. ‎م
414. ‎ال
415. ‎ال
416. ‎ال
417. ‎ر
418. ‎ال
419. ‎ام
420. ‎الما
421. ‎ررت
422. ‎را
423. ‎ل

It appears to matching exactly what you said for it to match.

Adding `\b` to match `\b[الإمارات]+\b` matches these 242 times:

1. ‎تدرك
2. ‎الإمارات
3. ‎العربية
4. ‎المتحدة
5. ‎الدولة
6. ‎التي
7. ‎لم
8. ‎أربعة
9. ‎على
10. ‎تأسيسها
11. ‎الدور
12. ‎الذي
13. ‎تؤديه
14. ‎الجاليات
15. ‎الوافدة
16. ‎إنجازاتها
17. ‎الهائلة
18. ‎لكن
19. ‎اليوم
20. ‎بعدما
21. ‎بات
22. ‎لبلادنا
23. ‎كيانها
24. ‎الخاص
25. ‎شبابها
26. ‎من
27. ‎الأوسع
28. ‎علما
29. ‎وثقافة
30. ‎العالم
31. ‎منحهم
32. ‎فرصا
33. ‎كبير
34. ‎منهم
35. ‎رجالا
36. ‎من
37. ‎خيرة
38. ‎الجامعات
39. ‎الخارج
40. ‎وهم
41. ‎يتحلون
42. ‎بالإبداع
43. ‎وروح
44. ‎المبادرة
45. ‎والريادة
46. ‎والطموح
47. ‎غالبا
48. ‎ما
49. ‎بمهاراتهم
50. ‎وبراعتهم
51. ‎استخدام
52. ‎التكنولوجيا
53. ‎على
54. ‎الشؤون
55. ‎العالمية
56. ‎والأهم
57. ‎من
58. ‎ذلك
59. ‎وطنهم
60. ‎ويحرصون
61. ‎على
62. ‎النهوض
63. ‎بالدور
64. ‎المنوط
65. ‎بهم
66. ‎للمساهمة
67. ‎لطالما
68. ‎أوليت
69. ‎للأهداف
70. ‎التي
71. ‎تسعى
72. ‎حملة
73. ‎التوطين
74. ‎إلى
75. ‎تحقيقها
76. ‎عبر
77. ‎إعطاء
78. ‎الأولوية
79. ‎للإماراتيين
80. ‎المؤهلين
81. ‎الراغبين
82. ‎التوظيف
83. ‎لقد
84. ‎علي
85. ‎أولد
86. ‎وأشعر
87. ‎بالفخر
88. ‎والاعتزاز
89. ‎لأن
90. ‎شركاتي
91. ‎ساهمت
92. ‎الإمارات
93. ‎ولا
94. ‎سيما
95. ‎قطاعات
96. ‎الضيافة
97. ‎والعقارات
98. ‎والإنشاءات
99. ‎والسيارات
100. ‎والتعليم
101. ‎أفتخر
102. ‎أعتبر
103. ‎من
104. ‎الجيل
105. ‎الذي
106. ‎المشقات
107. ‎تلك
108. ‎الأيام
109. ‎عندما
110. ‎كانت
111. ‎مدننا
112. ‎الرائعة
113. ‎قرى
114. ‎بالكاد
115. ‎يرد
116. ‎اسمها
117. ‎على
118. ‎الخريطة
119. ‎ربما
120. ‎تصديق
121. ‎الأمر
122. ‎الآن
123. ‎لكنني
124. ‎ما
125. ‎زلت
126. ‎أذكر
127. ‎نعاني
128. ‎للعثور
129. ‎على
130. ‎مياه
131. ‎كان
132. ‎نظامنا
133. ‎الغذائي
134. ‎يقتصر
135. ‎على
136. ‎السمك
137. ‎والبلح
138. ‎وحليب
139. ‎الناقة
140. ‎وأنا
141. ‎على
142. ‎الخصوص
143. ‎دولتنا
144. ‎الشيخ
145. ‎زايد
146. ‎سلطان
147. ‎آل
148. ‎نهيان
149. ‎والشيخ
150. ‎راشد
151. ‎آل
152. ‎مكتوم
153. ‎رحمة
154. ‎الله
155. ‎عليهما
156. ‎اللذين
157. ‎كانت
158. ‎قيادتهما
159. ‎ورؤيتهما
160. ‎الاستثنائية
161. ‎الثابتة
162. ‎وتصميمهما
163. ‎على
164. ‎النجاح
165. ‎الدافعة
166. ‎وراء
167. ‎الذي
168. ‎شهدته
169. ‎الإمارات
170. ‎لقد
171. ‎وضعا
172. ‎معا
173. ‎والامتياز
174. ‎يلتزم
175. ‎بها
176. ‎خلفاؤهما
177. ‎بكل
178. ‎أمانة
179. ‎وتفان
180. ‎وخير
181. ‎دليل
182. ‎على
183. ‎ذلك
184. ‎الإمارات
185. ‎من
186. ‎البلدان
187. ‎القليلة
188. ‎جدا
189. ‎العالم
190. ‎التي
191. ‎تشهد
192. ‎نموا
193. ‎اقتصاديا
194. ‎إنهيار
195. ‎الإقتصاد
196. ‎العالمي
197. ‎الذي
198. ‎العام
199. ‎والذي
200. ‎لا
201. ‎زال
202. ‎يرخي
203. ‎بظلاله
204. ‎على
205. ‎الولايات
206. ‎المتحدة
207. ‎وأوروبا
208. ‎وأماكن
209. ‎أخرى
210. ‎قبل
211. ‎سنوات
212. ‎توقع
213. ‎معلقون
214. ‎غربيون
215. ‎بلهجة
216. ‎منتشية
217. ‎تبتلع
218. ‎الرمال
219. ‎ربما
220. ‎كان
221. ‎ذلك
222. ‎مدعاة
223. ‎للضحك
224. ‎والسخرية
225. ‎بالنسبة
226. ‎إليهم
227. ‎لكن
228. ‎حتى
229. ‎الأكثر
230. ‎بينهم
231. ‎لا
232. ‎له
233. ‎من
234. ‎الإقرار
235. ‎بأننا
236. ‎من
237. ‎الآن
238. ‎الضحكة
239. ‎الأخيرة
240. ‎العام
241. ‎الماضي
242. ‎ل

There are some primitive systems that do not work correctly with Unicode (I’m looking at you, Javascript), or only do so by special magic.  See [UTS #18 Unicode Regular Expressions](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/) for what the standard says has to work under what circumstances.  The Microsoft docs for C# suggest that `\b` should work for you.

Comment: it is matching individual characters instead of the entire word..which is what i want...i have tried `\bالإمارات\b` which is working for english words but not for arabic...

Comment: @seadrag0n Boundaries are working for me. But if you use `\b[الإمارات]+\b` then it will only get words containing **only** those letters and no others. Do you want words than contain **any** of those letters instead plus any other letters around them, so `\b\pL*[الإمارات]\pL*\b`?  The latter regex produces 242 matches.

Comment: I need to match words that contain only those letters...i have tried `(الإمارات)\s[^\s]+\s[^\s]+` in c# and it matching the word `الإمارات` ending with a space but it is not matching if that word ends with any other character like a full stop . Example: `الإمارات،`

Comment: Well, `\b[الإمارات]+\b` works perfectly fine in Perl-based regex systems, since they actually understand Unicode.  No promises about anything on Microsoft, though. They probably don’t understand `\b` correctly.

Comment: @seadrag0n [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538201/regex-not-matching-unicode#comment2541862_2538375) suggests  it should work for you, too. But perhaps Microsoft is broken.

Comment: \b[الإمارات]+\b is working fine in c# for single Arabic words but now I am facing issue in matching multiple Arabic words...for example matching `اقتصاديا بعد` words are returning multiple matches...any way to fix this with \b[<arabic words here>]+\b regex?

Comment: @seadrag0n To match any of a set of words, use `\b(?:word1|word2|word3|word4)\b` etc.  You get the idea. But if you want multiple space-separated hits, you might want to bundle them up with something like `\b(?:[ لإمارات]+\b\s*)+`.  I suggest practicing on stuff in the Latin script — regular English — first to get a feel for how to do this.